# How to create a program using NSURLConnection?

Tags: objective-c

I need a simple example program using NSURLConnection which inturn uses NSURLRequest,NSURL Response classes.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/cocoa-application-driven-by-http-data.html